# In C# will returning a array variable return only the reference value or all the elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return, return-value

In java my professor explained that too copy the values of an array variable you must re-assign every element. For example...

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] Secondrry = myArray; 
// This will return only the reference to the myArray variable.
// Every element will still be null.

//In java every element must be re assigned.
int[] Secondrry = new int[3];
for(int i; i < myArray.length(); i++ )
{
    Secondrry[i] = myArray[i];
}
//Now every element of Secondrry will match myArray.
```

In C# do you also have to reassign every array element to pass the values of the array to a new variable? Or can you just have...

```
int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] Secondrry = myArray;
```

And finally when returning an array from a method in C#, will you be able to return the value just by specifying the variable? For example will this work?

```
public static int[] mymethod()
{   
    int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };        
    return myArray;
}

public static void mySecondmethod();
{
    int[] Secondrry = method();
}
```

Will the value of Secondrry have values 1, 2 and 3 or will the elements be null?

Comment: An array is probably the closest you can have to a pointer in C# without actually having an explicit pointer.

Comment: It's not clear what the confusion is - you are returning a reference to a single array object.  Are you asking if `method` creates a new array each time or if `newarray` points to a _copy_ of the array created in `method`?

Comment: It may be better to ask "this is what I want to do - does my code do that?"  That would make it clear what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: To answer your title question - yes arrays are reference types so you are returning a reference to the array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you will get a NEW instance of the array every time you call method(), assuming "declare array populated with values" does something like this:

```
var array = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
```

Here's an example of how to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish

```
private static int[] myStaticArray = method();
private static int[] method() {
    var array = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    return array;
}

public void first_method() {
    //gets you the same array reference every time
    int[] sameArray = myStaticArray;

    //gets you a copy of the array 
    int[] copyOfSameArray = (int[])myStaticArray.Clone();

    //gets you a new array each time
    int[] newArray = method();
}
```

Comment: so if i write a method that creates array a how would i return it to a variable?